# Why is $f(f^{-1}(E)) \subset E$ true instead of $f(f^{-1}(E)) = E$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was reading Rudin's Page 89 about continuity. There is one step where he uses the relation: $f(f^{-1}(E)) \subset E$. He also said that equality needs not hold in either case. I wonder why we can't say $f(f^{-1}(E)) = E$? Thanks!! Examples will be most appreciated because I can't think of an example where this equality doesn't hold.

Comment: Think of a non-surjective function.

Comment: the second one is not true if the function is not surjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{-1}(E)$ contains all elements that map to $E$. If $f$ does not reach all elements of $E$, then $f(f^{-1}(E))$ is a strictly smaller set than $E$.

Explicitly, if for instance $E = \{\square,\triangle\}$, $A = \{\bigcirc\}$ and $f: A \to E $ maps $\bigcirc$ to $\square$, then $f(f^{-1}(E)) = f(A) = f(\{\bigcirc\}) = \{\square\} \subsetneq \{\square,\triangle\} = E$.

Comment: As an example, consider the function $f:\{a,b\}\to\{a,b\}$ given by $f(a)=f(b)=a$. You have $f^{-1}(\{a,b\})=\{a,b\}$, but $f(f^{-1}(\{a,b\}))=\{a\}$.

Answer (score 2):

A specific example: consider a constant function
$$f\colon x\mapsto 0\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R.$$ 
For $E\subseteq \Bbb R$,

- If $0\notin E$, then $f^{-1}(E) = \emptyset$, so $f(f^{-1}(E)) = \emptyset$. Thus if $E \ne \emptyset$ then $f(f^{-1}(E)) \ne E$.
- If $0\in E$ then $f^{-1}(E) = \Bbb R$, so $f(f^{-1}(E)) = \{0\}$. Thus if $E \ne \{0\}$ then $f(f^{-1}(E)) \ne E$.

In general, for a function $f\colon X\to Y$, equality $f(f^{-1}(E)) = E$ holds for $E\subseteq Y$ iff $E\subseteq image(f)$, so it holds for a codomain $Y$ iff $f$ is a surjection onto $Y$.